# SonarQube: Is there a way to reset the technical debt analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

We have a build step in TFS 2015 (vNext build system, on prem) that kicks of a code analysis in SonarQube (also on prem | runs a service | database in SQLExpress). Last week we've updated to SonarQube 5.3 (from 5.2) and apparently the first analysis run on 5.3 caused all open issues to be closed/marked as fixed. 
We had a technical debt of several days (even weeks) and more than 1000 open issues. After the first run the debt was down to < 1h and just 2 issues. After another analysis run the debt is now 1h20min and 5 issues. All the previous issues are marked as 'Fixed'.

I've opened a few or those 'fixed' issues, but the code hasn't been changed. Most of the files haven't been touched in months.

What I have done so far:

- I've added a new project to SonarQube and changed the Project Key and Project Name in our build to the new temporary name. Started a build that caused an analysis to run. I was hoping a new analysis on a new project would discover all issues again, but also this analysis doesn't result in all previous found issues.
- I've installed SonarLint on VS2015 and it *does* show all issues (about 1500) on the same solution that was analysed.

Is there a way to 'reset' the SonarQube technical analysis so that it will analyse *all* files and create (or re-open) issues?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having nearly the exact same issue after upgrading from 5.2 to 5.3, except our projects are built with Bamboo and reported with the sonar-runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone experiencing this same issue:

Apparently the problem lies with the C# Plugin. Right before I updated the SonarQube instance from 5.2 to 5.3, I updated all the system plugins that had updates available. One of them was the C# Plugin. Version 4.3 was installed and was updated to 4.4. 
After "extensive" testing on a virtual machine with a clean SonarQube 5.2 installation, I found out that the SonarQube version had no influence on the technical debt analysis.